# Field injection from more than one components

Tags: android, dagger-2

Is in Dagger2 possible to inject from two modules like below ?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Inject ProvidedByOne one;
  @Inject ProvidedByTwo two;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        ((App) getApplication()).getOneComponent().inject(this);
        ((App) getApplication()).getSecondComponent().inject(this);
    } 
}
```

I have two independent modules and can't make it work. I got errors:

> Error:(16, 10) error: com.test.dagger.module.TwoModule.Two cannot be
>   provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or
>   @Produces-annotated method. com.test.activity.MoreActivity.two
>   [injected field of type: com.test.dagger.module.TwoModule.Two two]
>
> Error:(16, 10) error: com.test.dagger.module.OneModule.One cannot be
>   provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or
>   @Produces-annotated method. com.test.activity.MoreActivity.one
>   [injected field of type: com.test.dagger.module.OneModule.One one]

```
public class MoreActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Inject OneModule.One one;
    @Inject TwoModule.Two two;

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {

        ((App)getApplication()).getOneComponent().inject(this);
        ((App)getApplication()).getTwoComponent().inject(this);

        return SimpleFragment.newInstance(MoreActivity.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}

@Module
public class OneModule {
    public class One {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    One provideOne() {
        return new One();
    }
}

@Module
public class TwoModule {

    public class Two {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Two provideTwo() {
        return new Two();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = OneModule.class)
public interface OneComponent {
    void inject(MoreActivity activity);
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = TwoModule.class)
public interface TwoComponent {
    void inject(MoreActivity activity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, to use field injection, your component needs to be able to provide all of the dependencies marked with `@Inject`.

You can set the fields manually using provision methods though if you want to use multiple components per class.

```
@Module
public class OneModule {
    public class One {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    One provideOne() {
        return new One();
    }
}

@Module
public class TwoModule {

    public class Two {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Two provideTwo() {
        return new Two();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = OneModule.class)
public interface OneComponent {
    OneModule.One one();
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = TwoModule.class)
public interface TwoComponent {
    TwoModule.Two two();
}
```

And

```
public class MoreActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    OneModule.One one;
    TwoModule.Two two;

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {

        one = ((App)getApplication()).getOneComponent().one();
        two = ((App)getApplication()).getTwoComponent().two();

        return SimpleFragment.newInstance(MoreActivity.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks strange (no @Inject annotations...), but works. Do You think that i should avoid using more than one component per class like in my example or this is OK ?

Comment: Personally, I would use one `@Singleton` component, and bind all `@Module`s to that component. I tend to call it `ApplicationComponent`.

Comment: Any docs reference and also please explain the reason why we can't inject one type in more than one place?

Comment: I do not understand the question, this is about "you can't use field injection if the component you use to inject is unable to satisfy all @Inject annotated fields"